# How are render @users and render 'new' different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In RoR, I sometimes see:

```
render @users
```

or

```
render 'new'
```

How are the two different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, `render @users` is rendering a collection of objects of type `User` with a partial file named `_user.html.erb`, and `render 'new'` is rendering the `new` action & is equivalent to `render :action => new`.

Best to review the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) page in the Ruby on Rails Guides to understand how these two work & where they can be used appropriately, and the various in-built assumptions that make these and many other convenient `render` methods possible.

Comment: Prakash bhai can you please check out the new question i posted